# jetty - reload tag file in jar

Tags: java, jetty, tagfile

I have my main web project and a common project which houses my tag files. Currently I use jetty in exploded structure and I jar up my common project with my tag files and place into `web-inf/lib`.

When I make a change to my tag file, I can rejar and place into `web-inf/lib` again, though jetty is failing.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP
```

How can I set up jetty so I can rejar my tag files without restarting the server?

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason Jetty is unable to compile the JSP file is because it's running under a JRE instead of a JDK. It needs access to the compiler (which is not part of the JRE just the JDK) to turn JSP source into bytecode (with a Servlet step in between).